# How to limit what is available for a role in Administration menu ?

Tags: 7, users, forms

I am using Drupal 7 and installed the Administration menu. It works fine and I am really happy with it but after creating a new role, and also creating a new user for that role, he seems to have the entire menu available even though permissions are restricted.

To clarify, I removed permissions to flush cache and administer blocks. When he clicks those links, it says access denied but he can still click the links. How do I keep those links he cannot click from appearing in the menu at all?

Answer (score 1):

Check if this user role is marked as the "Administrator Role" on User Settings.

There is also an option to rebuild the menu tree on Admin Menu settings...